# How to get lambda/function signature in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, reflection

I have developed the code below:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.rabbitmq.client.Delivery

typealias MessageHandler<T> = (payload: T, args: HashMap<String, String>) -> Unit
class MessageRouter {
    private var handlers: HashMap<String, Function<Unit>> = hashMapOf()

    fun <T> bind(routingKey: String, handler: MessageHandler<T>) : MessageRouter {
        handlers[routingKey] = handler
        return this
    }


    fun consume(message: Delivery) {
        if(message.envelope.routingKey in handlers) {
            val currentHandler = handlers[message.envelope.routingKey]
            if(message.properties.contentType == "application/json") {
                ///// TODO: Get function signature!
                val gson = Gson()
                //// TODO: Deserialize data and call the handler function 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To be used as follows:

```
val messageRouter = MessageRouter()
                val messageRouter = MessageRouter()
    

messageRouter.bind(EventSubscriberConstants.REGISTRATION_ROUTING_KEY) { user: UserDTO, _ -> register(user) }
        basicConsume(
            queueName, true,
            { _, message ->
                messageRouter.consume(message)
            }, null, null
        )
```

I need the input lambda signature to extract UserDTO class and use Gson to deserialize it and process. I can not find any way to get function signature in Kotlin!

Comment: What does line `8")), UserDTO::class.java))` mean? It seems that some code is missing

Comment: @fdermishin Sorry! The one edited the question has added it mistakenly! I Fixed it

Comment: You want to get runtime type of `T`? I believe it's impossible due to type erasure (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-erasure). It will be `Any?`.